# Watchkit notification scene mandatory?

Tags: iphone, push-notification, watchkit

i am a little bit confusing about Watchkit notification because the documentation say:

> Apps are not required to do anything to support notifications. The system provides a default notification interface that displays the alert message from the notification. However, apps can customize the notification interface and include custom graphics, content, and branding.

My app receive remote notification, i want that Apple Watch notification, but without customization. In this case notification scene is mandatory inside the project or is necessary only if you want make a custom view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notification interfaces are needed only if you wish to customize them. If you don't include them, the Watch OS will present the alerts using a default interface.